# Java Weird NullPointerException When Reversing a Linked List

Tags: java

I'm working on a LeetCode problem called "**Palindrome Linked List**", where a singly linked list is given, determine if it is a palindrome. For example, if the input is 1->2->2->1, it should output true.

I solved it by using extra space (converting the list into an ArrayList), and now I'm trying to solve it by another approach, **reversing the 2nd half of list and then compare the two halves**. Although I might have not implemented the idea in the best way, I expected the code to either work or output a wrong answer (then I could improve the code). However, a weird NullPointerException happened, and I couldn't figure out why.

My code is shown below, and the **input list for testing is 1->2->3**. I also added some prints to help debug.

```
// reverse the 2nd half of list and then compare the two halves

class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        int n = 0; // list length
        ListNode p = head;
        while (p != null) { // obtain list length n 
            n++;
            p = p.next;
        }
        p = head;


        int m = 0;
        ListNode prev = null, curr = null, temp = null;
        while (p != null) { // reverse the 2nd half of list
            m++;
            if (m == n/2 + 1) {
                prev = p;
                curr = p.next;
                p = p.next;

                System.out.println(curr.val);
                System.out.println(curr);
                //System.out.println(p);
            }
            else if (m > n/2 + 1) {
                //System.out.println(p);
                System.out.println(curr);
                //System.out.println(curr.val);

                temp = curr.next;
                curr.next = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = temp;
                p = p.next;
            }
            else 
                p = p.next;
        }


        int k = 1;
        while (k < n/2 + 1) { // compare the two halves, prev points at the last node
            if (head.val != prev.val)
                return false;
            head = head.next;
            prev = prev.next;
            k++;
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

The **output** (when input 1->2->3, plus some print statements) is:

```
NullPointerException thrown at the line: temp = curr.next; (which is inside the else if)

the code also prints:
3
ListNode@77a567e1
ListNode@77a567e1
null
```

curr is referring to the last node, so curr.val is 3. What I don't understand is why the **two System.out.println(curr)** give different outputs. Shouldn't curr be referring to the last node? Where does the **null** in the output come from? I think that is the key for why NullPointerException happened there.

I'm very confused right now, if someone could help me understand what went wrong, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

Edit: Since this is a LeetCode question, the ListNode class is predefined, I don't need to write it myself.

Comment: It seems that the `ListNode` class is your custom implementation and it is missing.
Also, it is not quite clear how you build your list which is actually represented by a single `ListNode`

Comment: @Alex Rudenko Hi Alex, thanks for answering. This is a LeetCode question where the ListNode class is predefined, so I don't need to write it. You can see the question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/ You'll see what I mean if you choose Java on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your given input is 1->2->3 so your n is 3.

Before Entering the while loop you have initialized

> curr = null;

Your program enters while loop

**First Iteration**

- m++;      value of m=1
- 1 == 3/2+1 false so enter else if again false so it goes to else

values after 1st iteration

m = 1; curr=null prev=null and p=2(points to node value 2)

**Second iteration**

- m=2
- 2 == 3/2+1 true goes inside if
- prev = 1 , curr & p = 3(node with value 3)
- Print curr.val which is 3 and curr which prints "ListNode@77a567e1"

Values after 2nd iteration

m = 2;  prev=2, curr & p=3(node with value 3)

**Third Iteration**

- m=3
- 3>3/2+1 true so enters else if
- Print curr prints "ListNode@77a567e1"
- temp = curr.next as curr is 3 its next is null
- curr = temp; as temp = null curr is null

**Forth Iteration**

```
so as curr is null on forth iteration it prints null and throws null pointer exception.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think it ever entered the 4th iteration, since p should also = null at the end of the 3rd iteration, which wouldn't satisfy the while loop condition. The exception happened during the 3rd iteration.

Comment: Ahh I finally got it. In the 3rd iteration, after "p = p.next", p isn't equal to null, because the link is already reversed, instead p.val = 2. Hence, the loop indeed goes into the 4th iteration and throws the exception. Thanks. I just instead set "p = curr", and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should have implemented your `isPalindrome` method using `LinkedList` from Java common Collections using `iterator` and `descendingIterator`:

```java
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
System.out.printf("list: %s palindrome: %s%n", list,  isPalindrome(list));
// ...

  public boolean isPalindrome(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    Iterator<Integer> directIterator = list.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> reverseIterator = list.descendingIterator();
    int count = list.size() / 2;
    while (directIterator.hasNext() && reverseIterator.hasNext() && count-- > 0) {
      if (directIterator.next().intValue() != reverseIterator.next().intValue()) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Update: a solution for the requested single-linked list using a reversed list:

```java
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        // empty and single element list is palindrome
        if (null == head || null == head.next) {
            return true;
        }
        // build reverse linked list
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode tail = new ListNode(curr.val);
        tail.next = null;
        ListNode prev = null;
        int size = 1;
        while (null != curr.next) {
            prev = tail;
            curr = curr.next;
            tail = new ListNode(curr.val);
            tail.next = prev;
            size++;
        }
        // move both from head and from tail to the middle element
        int half = size / 2;
        curr = head;
        prev = tail;
        while (null != curr && null != prev && half-- > 0) {
            if (curr.val != prev.val) {
                return false;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
            prev = prev.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for another reply! Yeah I know there are other ways to implement the idea, but I really want to know why the exception happened in my code, which I've been wondering for hours.